# jQuery autocomplete combobox with default selected value

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am using jQuery Autocomplete with combobox. I am trying to select default value like PHP option. I hope you understand my qyetion.

Any ideas or suggestions? Thanks.

My Code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Combobox</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<style>
.custom-combobox {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.custom-combobox-toggle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-left: -1px;
    padding: 0;
/* support: IE7 */
*height: 1.7em;
*top: 0.1em;
}
.custom-combobox-input {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0.3em;
}
</style>
<script>
(function( $ ) {
$.widget( "custom.combobox", {
_create: function() {
this.wrapper = $( "<span>" )
.addClass( "custom-combobox" )
.insertAfter( this.element );
this.element.hide();
this._createAutocomplete();
this._createShowAllButton();
},
_createAutocomplete: function() {
var selected = this.element.children( ":selected" )
value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "";
this.input = $( "<input>" )
.appendTo( this.wrapper )
.val( value )
.attr( "title", "" )
.addClass( "custom-combobox-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-left" )
.autocomplete({
delay: 0,
minLength: 0,
source: $.proxy( this, "_source" )
})
.tooltip({
tooltipClass: "ui-state-highlight"
});
this._on( this.input, {
autocompleteselect: function( event, ui ) {
ui.item.option.selected = true;
this._trigger( "select", event, {
item: ui.item.option
});
},
autocompletechange: "_removeIfInvalid"
});
},
_createShowAllButton: function() {
var input = this.input,
wasOpen = false;
$( "<a>" )
.attr( "tabIndex", -1 )
.attr( "title", "Show All Items" )
.tooltip()
.appendTo( this.wrapper )
.button({
icons: {
primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
},
text: false
})
.removeClass( "ui-corner-all" )
.addClass( "custom-combobox-toggle ui-corner-right" )
.mousedown(function() {
wasOpen = input.autocomplete( "widget" ).is( ":visible" );
})
.click(function() {
input.focus();
// Close if already visible
if ( wasOpen ) {
return;
}
// Pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
input.autocomplete( "search", "" );
});
},
_source: function( request, response ) {
var matcher = new RegExp( $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i" );
response( this.element.children( "option" ).map(function() {
var text = $( this ).text();

if ( this.value && ( !request.term || matcher.test(text) ) )
return {
label: text,
value: text,
option: this
};
}) );
},
_removeIfInvalid: function( event, ui ) {
// Selected an item, nothing to do
if ( ui.item ) {
return;
}
// Search for a match (case-insensitive)
var value = this.input.val(),
valueLowerCase = value.toLowerCase(),
valid = false;
this.element.children( "option" ).each(function() {
if ( $( this ).text().toLowerCase() === valueLowerCase ) {
this.selected = valid = true;
return false;
}
});
// Found a match, nothing to do
if ( valid ) {
return;
}
// Remove invalid value
this.input
.val( "" )
.attr( "title", value + " didn't match any item" )
.tooltip( "open" );
this.element.val( "" );
this._delay(function() {
this.input.tooltip( "close" ).attr( "title", "" );
}, 2500 );
this.input.data( "ui-autocomplete" ).term = "";
},
_destroy: function() {
this.wrapper.remove();
this.element.show();
}
});
})( jQuery );
$(function() {
$( "#combobox" ).combobox();
$( "#toggle" ).click(function() {
$( "#combobox" ).toggle();
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="ui-widget">
<select id="combobox">
<option value="">Select one...</option>
<option value="ActionScript">ActionScript</option>
<option value="AppleScript">AppleScript</option>
<option value="Asp">Asp</option>
<option value="BASIC">BASIC</option>
<option value="C">C</option>
<option value="C++">C++</option>
<option value="Clojure">Clojure</option>
<option value="COBOL">COBOL</option>
<option value="ColdFusion">ColdFusion</option>
<option value="Erlang">Erlang</option>
<option value="Fortran">Fortran</option>
<option value="Groovy">Groovy</option>
<option value="Haskell">Haskell</option>
<option value="Java">Java</option>
<option value="JavaScript">JavaScript</option>
<option value="Lisp">Lisp</option>
<option value="Perl">Perl</option>
<option value="PHP">PHP</option>
<option value="Python">Python</option>
<option value="Ruby">Ruby</option>
<option value="Scala">Scala</option>
<option value="Scheme">Scheme</option>
</select>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need be more specific about your question.if possible create a fiddle for your scenario,we`ll have a look at it.

Comment: @dreamweiver Currently default value is nothing in my combobox and i want to selected value is PHP. My jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mzQ7m/

Comment: You just need to set the attribute **Selected** for the option which u want to keep as default. here is the fiddle for the same http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/mzQ7m/1/

Comment: @dreamweiver Thanks for your resonance but i want to pass php variable inside jquery code. Not like selected attribute. Any idea about this?

Comment: hmmm, that shouldnt be any difficult. just need to set the attribute of the "php" option as **selected**.ill do it for u if you need that way.

Comment: ya sure. plz i need help

Comment: Is this what you wanted ,http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/mzQ7m/3/

Comment: @dreamweiver Great work bro. Thanks :)

Comment: Thats great, one more thing,i`ll add this as a answer below.just check it as a answer, this will reduce the no of open questions from the SO questons pool.

Comment: @dreamweiver Hey I need your small help if you can. onchange I want to pass value inside setDefault("") when user change option value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this can be done by looping through all the values until we find the target value and then set the attribute **selected** to respective option tag.

**JS CODE:**

```
setDefault("Scala");
//function to set the selected value as default
function setDefault(defValue) {
  $('#combobox option').each(function () {
    if (($(this).attr('value')) === defValue) {
        $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
    }
  });
}
```

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/mzQ7m/3/) @ JS Fiddle

Answer (score 2):

The code that dreamweiver posted can be simplified further. There's no need to loop through the options, you can use `option[value=""]` and string concatenation to build the selector.

```
setDefault("Scala");
//function to set the selected value as default
function setDefault(defValue) {
    $('#combobox option[value="' + defValue + '"]').attr('selected', 'selected');
}
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/E2YMw/)